# How to eliminate id path parameter in swagger-ui in DRF-YASG for DRF and DJANGO

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

I'm using DRF-YASG to document API in Swagger and want to customizing/eliminating some fields shown in parameters

I'm running the project with  Django 2.1.7, DRF 3.9.2 and DRF-YASG 1.14.0.

So, I want to eliminate the ID which is shown in swagger-ui (like a 'string' and 'path'), cause I have it in the body request through Schema, but swagger-ui shows the id (automatically generated field) in parameters.

In the screen below, you can see the problem:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5421182/54859641-70359d00-4cee-11e9-9b12-79ab57d12495.png

Here, my code...

```
request_category_put = openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT, required=['id','name'],
    properties={
        'id': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER, 
                title='Id', readOnly=True,
                description='Id of the category'), ### <-- I have the ID here.
        'name': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING, 
                title='Category', maxLength=200, minLength=1,
                description='Name of the category')
    },
    example={
        'id' : 1,
        'name' : 'Business',
    }
)

class CategoryDetail(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[authorization],
        request_body=request_category_put,
        responses = {
            '200' : response_category,
            '400': 'Bad Request',
            '404': 'Not found'
        },        
        security=[security_endpoint],
        operation_id='Update category',
        operation_description='Update a specific category.',
    )
    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=pk)
        serializer = CategorySerializer(category, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(modified_by=self.request.user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

When I add the field in `manual_parameters` in `@swagger_auto_schema`, only change the attributes of this... but the field still is there.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for how `manual_parameters` is implemented, it doesn't look possible. See: 
[`drf_yasg.inspectors.view.get_operation()`](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/blob/master/src/drf_yasg/inspectors/view.py)

```
    def get_operation(self, operation_keys=None):
        operation_keys = operation_keys or self.operation_keys

        consumes = self.get_consumes()
        produces = self.get_produces()

        body = self.get_request_body_parameters(consumes)
        query = self.get_query_parameters()
        parameters = body + query
        parameters = filter_none(parameters)
        parameters = self.add_manual_parameters(parameters)
```

in that function there is a call to `add_manual_parameters()` which only adds the overrides you have specified to the existing list of params. So you'd have to add an option either to replace the existing params or add a new manual_overrides_remove which would remove specific parameters. I would suggest raising an Issue in the [drf_yasg github](https://github.com/axnsan12/drf-yasg/issues) pages or submit a PR to add this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your parameter name that you want to exclude from swagger request description in serrializer Meta-field `read_only_fields`

Like as

```
class SomeSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...
        read_only_fields = ["id", ...]
```